# Copy files via Maven plugin when publishing on JBoss

Tags: java, maven, jboss, applet

I want to run a Java-Applet.
I use a JBoss Server.
I use Maven.
I use Eclipse.
I deploy my Web-Archive inside an Enterprise Archive onto the Server by using Eclipse.

For the Applet I need the Applet's .class-file in an accessible folder for the applet.html.
My idea was to copy the .class-from the target-folder to the resources-folder of my Web-Archive. So I added following plugin to the pom.xml of the Web-Maven-Project:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-applet-related-classes</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>

                       <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/LMS-Admin-Web-  0.0.1/resources/applet</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/target/classes/de/test/lms/applet</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I think I'm messing up the phase and the goal. It worked once when I had the goal "install" for the package and executed "mvn clean install" inside my project-folder. The problem is when I use right-click->publish in Eclipse. I don't know, what goals are run than. I tried a lot around, but it doesn't apply in the JBoss' standalone/deployments/... file-system.
Turns out this is also really hard to google. So I'd be thankful for any ideas, links or other help!

EDIT:
I found out, that the classes-folder in the target-folder is edited when I publish, but the WEB-Folder which is packaged to the WAR-File isn't. Maybe I need a phase, which is before packaging? I'm to investigate further tomorrow.

Comment: The phase was 'package'...
I tried 'package' as a goal, because I thought you might have meant that, but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

In my project I also needed an applet, which needed to be copied to the `classes` dir. Only difference is that I stored the applet as an artifact (thus in a jar). I'm using the `process-resources` phase for that. In your case probably too.

I'll add my solution in case you want to package your applet. Which you'll need to do, if you want to [sign it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908748/how-do-i-sign-a-java-applet-for-use-in-a-browser).

```
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-signed-applet</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>myapplet</artifactId>
                                        <version>${myapplet.version}</version>
                                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/path/to/applet</outputDirectory>
                                        <destFileName>myapplet.jar</destFileName>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
```

If you are using Eclipse, you need to add plugin lifecycle-mapping (if you don't have it already) in your `pluginManagement`. Make sure that goal `copy` has action `execute`.

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-dependency-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [2.2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>copy</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
...
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and I'll probably use your approach. Still I'm really curious what would solve my problem, even if it might not by long-term relevant, because of the signing-process you mentioned ;)

Comment: I tried your approach. I had to put the <plugins> into <pluginManagement>, because otherwise I had this error: "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration".
Now that I have a new Applet-Maven-Project, I added it to the dependencies of my WAR-Project. This .jar is deployed (to the WEB-INF/lib folder). But a 'myapplet.jar' is nowhere to be found.
Of course I replaced your placeholders in the <artifactItem>-tag.
Can I somehow see, what Eclipse does Maven-wise when I publish?

Comment: You need to execute the dependency-plugin in your lifecycle mapping. I'll add an example in the answer.

Comment: I seem to be getting ahead, slowly. Now I have following Error:

Error copying artifact from D:\Repos\LMS\LMS-Admin-Applet\target\classes to D:\Repos\LMS\LMS-Admin-Web\target\classes\applet\myApplet.jar (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.2:copy:copy-signed-applet:process-resources)

Google only suggests Bug-reports

Comment: Why are you copying from D:\Repos\LMS\LMS-Admin-Applet\target\classes? Normally it should copy from your local repo... (if you used the above code)

Comment: What part would specify the copying from the filesystem and not the repository?

Here is the complete build-part of my pom:
http://pastebin.com/v5bfSkP4

Comment: Do you build the applet.jar in the same pom?

Comment: The Applet is a different Maven project. They are both as modules in a parent project. The Web-Project has the Applet-Project as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the Git Param Plugin : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin

It should help  you.