# Create JavaApplet without ask for security warning

Tags: java, applet

I only have one class in my .jar file and don't need user to click for security warning. How can I display it from popping up?

Comment: 'How can I display it from popping up?' I'm having a hard time on this part... Do you mean prevent?

Comment: You can't.  This is part of the applet plugin

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean "How can I prevent it from popping up."

You'll want to look into the difference between signed and self signed applets.

[How do I sign a Java applet for use in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908748/how-do-i-sign-a-java-applet-for-use-in-a-browser)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet

http://www.narendranaidu.com/2007/11/3-easy-steps-to-self-sign-applet-jar.html

Long story short, your user is going to have to have at least 1 security popup they will have to accept.