# How to sign an Applet?

Tags: java, file, security, applet, digital-signature

I have created an applet which will play an animation. But while displaying it in browser it gives `java.io.FilePermision` error. My applet is not signed. Please give me some information, how to sign an applet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908748/how-do-i-sign-a-java-applet-for-use-in-a-browser

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html

Comment: Are these resources supplied by you or the user?  If by you, access them by `URL` (in a sand-boxed applet).