# Getting exception java.net.SocketPermission

Tags: java

I have jApplet where I want to send buffer to server and dump on it, but why AccessControlException I am not able to understand.

```
 java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission endpoint:8080 connect,resolve)
            at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
            at sun.awt.AWTSecurityManager.checkPermission(AWTSecurityManager.java:959)
            at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
            at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Applets should be signed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908748/how-do-i-sign-a-java-applet-for-use-in-a-browser

Comment: Ya I signed it, still I am getting same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the exception, Your application does not have rights to  access the socket 8080.

```
grant{
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1099", "connect, resolve";
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1024-", "connect, resolve";
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1024-", "accept, resolve";
};
```

Ref : https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1178887 it may help you

See it too : [Java RMI AccessControlException: access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427473/java-rmi-accesscontrolexception-access-denied)