# Unsigned Applet in a WAR deployed using Apache Tomcat for JRE 7u45

Tags: java, tomcat, applet

I have a WAR file that is deployed on Apache Tomcat.  The WAR file is running an Applet via a browser.  Since Java 7u45, JRE is giving me an error of "An unsigned application from the location below is requesting permission to run".

My questions how do I sign an Applet if the files in my Applet are not jar files, but .class files?

Below is an example of my applet tag I use in my JSP page.

```
<applet code=TicTacToe.class 
        width=120 height=120>
</applet>
```

How do I make the error "An unsigned application from the location below is requesting permission to run" go away. This error started occurring in Java 7u45. Apparently this is part of the enhanced security features.

Comment: Don't sign applets, if you sign them it will not working.

Comment: How do I make the error "An unsigned application from the location below is requesting permission to run" go away.  This error started occurring in Java 7u45.  Apparently this is part of the enhanced security features.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The signature information is contained in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file, which is part of a jar file. So you will need to package it.

Comment: I tried packaging all my class files in a jar.  Now, the applet will not load.

Comment: Did you sign it correctly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908748/how-do-i-sign-a-java-applet-for-use-in-a-browser

Comment: of course it's signed correctly, because I am using the same certificate for another application using Java webstart.  I now need the applet signed